# Jquery how to select an input using his name

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Please I have an input text and I want to add a class to it :

```
<input type="text" name ="var[1]" />
```

I tried this line but no success :

```
$('input[name=var[1]]').addClass('invalidField');
```

PS : This input does not exist in markup, but its displayed using ajax !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use quotes and be sure to call it once the dom is ready :

```
$(function(){
    $('input[name="var[1]"]').addClass('invalidField');
});
```

The quotes are optional only when the value is "simple". If it contains parenthesis, spaces, braces, etc., jQuery doesn't get where the value ends and can't parse the expression.

Comment: Thank you Dystroy a lot. I have missed the quotes !

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input[name="var[1]"]').addClass('invalidField');
```

you missed  ""